# Is there a way of adding a quick link on the administration page to a module's configuration?

Tags: prestashop

Is it possible to add a link on the top menubar of the Administration page (Catalog, Orders, Customers...) going straight to a module's configuration page? I've inherited a large module with a ton of messy code that I'd really like to leave be, if at all possible.

The only requirement is that its configuration **has** to be accessible from that menu bar in particular (or, if there's no other possible option, from the quick links section; this one in particular can easily be achieved, except for the token part).

**EDIT:** I managed to pull it off by creating an Admin controller, but I am having issues generating the correct access token. I do not really know what to do to fix it and, as such, I am hereby launching (yet another) bounty.

Here's the code I am using for the redirect:

```
<?php

class AdminMultiBlockController extends AdminController 
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        global $cookie;

        // this doesn't really work
        $tab = 'adminmodules';
        $token = Tools::getAdminToken($tab.(int)(Tab::getIdFromClassName($tab)).(int)($cookie->id_employee));

        Tools::redirectAdmin('index.php?controller=adminmodules&configure=egr_MultiBlockSlider&token=' . $token);
    }
}
```

My workaround was to force a working token, but this won't do.

What am I doing wrong? What parameters should I put inside the getAdminToken() function in order to successfully access a module's configuration?

I am currently using Prestashop v1.5.1.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not being able to reproduce the problem, I can only guess.
However, try with the following code:

```
$url  = 'index.php?controller=AdminModules&configure=egr_MultiBlockSlider';
$url .= '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
Tools::redirectAdmin($url);
```

Comment: Perfect as usual. Rock on man, I'd totally pay you a beer right now :)